# Corrupted international characters because of no "SET NAMES utf8;" in TYPO3

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, typo3

I've got some problem in one of the TYPO3 Polish sites with character encoding. There was no `setDBinit=SET NAMES utf8;` parameter set in configuration.
Everything works okay (frontend & backend) but the export from the database. All international characters are corrupted when I search database via PhpMyAdmin or try to export database with data.

The official page `http://wiki.typo3.org/UTF-8_support#SET_NAMES_utf8.3B` says:

> Without SET NAMES utf8; your TYPO3 UTF-8 setup might work, but chances are that database content entered after the conversion to UTF-8 has each international character stored as two separate, garbled latin1 chars.
>
> If you check your database using phpMyAdmin and find umlauts in new content being shown as two garbled characters, this is the case. If this happens to you, you cannot just add the above statement any more. Your output for the new content will be broken. Instead you have to correct the newly added special chars first. **This is done most easily by just deleting the content, setting the option as described above and re-entering it**.

Is there any other way to repair corrupted characters? There is a lot of content to edit now...
I tried almost every combination of export encoding and converting to another encoding and so on and so far I failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try mysqldump to convert from ISO-8859-1 to utf-8:

```
mysqldump --user=username --password=password --default-character-set=latin1 --skip-set-charset dbname > dump.sql
chgrep latin1 utf8 dump.sql (or when you prefer  sed -i "" 's/latin1/utf8/g' dump.sql) 
mysql --user=username --password=password --execute="DROP DATABASE dbname; CREATE DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;"
mysql --user=username --password=password --default-character-set=utf8 dbname < dump.sql
```

Comment: Just use one of the 2 expression. Not all together.